# How to get values from inner object in the hashmap in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap. Object contains info like name, address, email. I am able to iterate HashMap but not able to get values from the Object. Here is my code if anyone can please show me a proper way to do this.

```
public void getData(){

    // hashmap is records<key, Object>
    // Object contains properties name, address, email

    Iterator it = records.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();

        Object key =  entry.getKey();
        Object val =  entry.getValue();

        // this gets me through hashmap
        // how do I get name, address and email from object?

    }

}
```

Comment: You should not be using a `HashMap` without Generics in modern code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using generics, you will need to explicitly cast the result of `entry.getValue()` to the class of the object with name, address, and email.

You didn't provide that actual class, but it might be something like:

```
    Person val =  Person.class.cast(entry.getValue());
    name = val.getName();
    // and so on....
```

Comment: One could argue that in 2013 if you're not using Generics you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use `Person val =  (Person) entry.getValue();` ?

Comment: @johnchen902 Because `Class.cast()` will throw a `ClassCastException` if the object isn't an instance of the class.

Comment: @BrianRoach `Person val = (Person) entry.getValue();` will throw a `ClassCastException` if the object isn't an instance too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply get the item by calling `.getValue()`.  You need to assign the object to whatever object type you're using.  You shouldn't simply cast, because that will only satisfy syntactical constraints by java's compiler.  You want to make sure that your object is indeed what you think it is.  For example:

```
  Object o = it.next();

  if (o instanceof MyObjType)
  {
        MyObjType obj = (MyObjType) o.
  }
```

Comment: You called `it.next()` twice and the two calls return different value.

Comment: You didn't change anything exactly.

Comment: Uh... you still have two variable named `o`.

Comment: Thank you all, i got the idea now.

Comment: No problem.  Can you please accept one of our answers? Upvotes are also appreciated.

Comment: I see that you're new to SO.  When people answer questions, and give correct/complete answers, one (ideally) should upvote (you can upvote any number of questions/answers) answers that you think are good/accept the answer that you think best answers your question. People put their time into answering posts, and in return, they get reputation that comes from upvotes/accepted answers,etc. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your name, address, email is in a object of type **PersonalInfo**. Then when you define your iterator use **generics** as follows -

```
Iterator<PersonalInfo> it = records.entrySet().iterator();
```

You can also define your Map that way. No need to use Object as you know the date or object that the Object(Polymorphic reference) will hold.

Do define your Map like -

```
Map<key, PersonalInfo> records = new HashMap<key, PersonalInfo>();
```

Inside your PersonalInfo class you will have **getter** and **setter** methods for each variable like name,email etc.Now you can extract data as follows -

```
PersonalInfo myInfo =  entry.getValue();
String name = myInfo.getName();
String email = myInfo.getEmail();
//etc...
```